# Dimension of space spanned by minors

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, determinant

Let $M_{n,m}$ denote the set of $n\times m$ matrices over a field $\mathbb{C}$. The set of $k\times k$ minors are homogeneous polynomial functions of degree $k$ in the entries of the matrix. What is the dimension of the vector space they span inside the vector space of degree $k$ polynomials?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Aren't they linearly independent?

Comment: Please, google "Eagon-Northcott" or "Eagon-Northcott complex".